# Conformal prediction nonconformity measure

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, uncertainty, conformal-prediction

I want to implement offline inductive conformal prediction for a bianry classificstion task but I have an issue with finding an appropriate nonconformity measure.
Shafer proposes [the Nearest neighbor](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.3188.pdf)

> A(B, z) : = distance to z’s nearest neighbor in B with the same label / distance to z’s nearest neighbor in B with a different label

while Dashevskiy in a traffic classification task proposed [the nearest centroid](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/nonconformity-score#:%7E:text=Conformal%20predictors%20are%20based%20on,the%20selected%20group%20of%20examples.)

> Unlike the nearest neighbors algorithm, the nearest centroid (NC) algorithm (see [24]) does not require computing the distances between each pair of objects. Instead, it measures the distance between an object and the centroid (i.e., the average) of all objects belonging to the same class.

Keep in mind that my X is a ~2000 bit vector that I would have to reduce to find the centroid. My datasets are in 1000-10000.
Do you have any better way to calculate the nonconformity?

Comment: There are much better ways to compute nonconformity measures for classification problems and the two classical measures are: * hinge loss - which is 1 - probability of true class. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAwxo.png * margin - These are general high performance NCMs that I am covering in my book 'Practical Guide to Applied Conformal Prediction: Learn and apply the best uncertainty frameworks to your industry applications' https://a.co/d/6sWiqoU The ones mentioned in the papers are ad hoc NCMs.